# Bash debugger of Visual Studio Code using WSL Ubuntu in Windows does not stop in breakpoints

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, debugging, windows-subsystem-for-linux, breakpoints

I'm having issues debugging a Bash script in Visual Studio Code using the WSL extension. Despite setting breakpoints in my Bash script, the debugger runs the script without stopping at any breakpoints.

As far as I understand, I have installed all the needed extensions inside the remote WSL: Ubuntu-20.04. I have also set up the bashdb extension as suggested. This is my **launch.json**:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "type": "bashdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Bash-Debug (simplest configuration)",
            "program": "${file}",
            "showDebugOutput": true,
            "terminalKind": "integrated",
            "trace": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried changing the `terminalKind` to `debugConsole`, but the behaviour is the same. It runs but it doesn't stop on breakpoints.
This is the script that I have been running to test it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export NICE_VAR=10
export ANOTHER_VAR=20

for i in {0..25..5}
do  
    export NICE_VAR=$((NICE_VAR+i)) # BREAKPOINT
    echo $NICE_VAR
done

for ((i=1;i<=25;i+=1))
do  
    export ANOTHER_VAR=$((ANOTHER_VAR+i)) # BREAKPOINT
    echo $ANOTHER_VAR
done

if [ $ANOTHER_VAR -gt $NICE_VAR ]
then  
    echo "ANOTHER bigger than nice" # BREAKPOINT
else  
    echo "Nice is bigger or equal"
fi
```

When checking the output on the debug console, there is recognition of the position of the breakpoints but then it gets "No breakpoints have been set". This is the output filtered by lines containing breakpoints:

```
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":1,"command":"initialize","success":true,"body":
{"supportsConditionalBreakpoints":true,"supportsConfigurationDoneRequest":false,"supportsEvaluateForHovers":
true,"supportsStepBack":false,"supportsSetVariable":false}}

##1 sourceFrom client: setBreakpoints({"source":{"name":"Debugging_test.sh","path":"../Debugging_test.sh"},
"lines":[7,13,19],"breakpoints":[{"line":7},{"line":13},{"line":19}],"sourceModified":false})

To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"stdout","output":
"No breakpoints have been set.\n"}}

No breakpoints have been set.

To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":6,"command":"setBreakpoints","success":true,"body":
{"breakpoints":[{"verified":true,"line":null,"id":null},{"verified":true,"line":null,"id":null},{"verified":
true,"line":null,"id":null}]}}

From client: setExceptionBreakpoints({"filters":[]})

To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":7,"command":"setExceptionBreakpoints","success":true}
```

I already tried the solution indicated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44068717/18255654
but it seems specific for C++ and it didn't change the behavior. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insights into why the breakpoints might not be working?